# What is the limit of use of Redux in terms of performance?

Tags: performance, react-native, mobile, redux, react-redux

I'm working on an application in React Native, with a lot of useless use of Redux, and once a person told me that it is good to avoid using Redux as much as possible, only use it in really necessary cases, because it would weigh the app, making it slow, because every action would go through all reducers until they find their own case, I would like an opinion from someone who knows the subject, about how far to use Redux, if it can cause slowness, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. you can check this particular blog https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367 This blog is written by the creator of redux itself

Answer (score 0):

[The question of "all reducers handle all actions" is not a concern by itself](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#wont-calling-all-my-reducers-for-each-action-be-slow), as that's typically just a few function calls.  If a reducer doesn't care about a given action, it just immediately returns the existing state.

Typically the cost of running reducers is fairly small - it's the cost of updating the UI that takes the bulk of the work time after dispatching an action.